# Can't change folder name of project in Yii

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii, yii-url-manager

I have a created a project named "ProjectName".

I want to change the project name to "NewProject"

I can't change the folder name of the project.

If i change the folder name, URL Manager functions not working.

But i can run proper by disable URLManager functions in /confing/main.php and put **index.php?** in the url

I have a proper .htaccess file.

No hard codes in my project.

Is any problem in server or code?

Comment: Did you clear all yii cache?

Comment: Put you url manager code in `config/main.php` and `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem.

I add the following lines in apache httpd.conf file.

<Directory /var/www/path/to/NewProject>
    AllowOverride All
    Options Includes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>

These lines helps to look the .htaccess file. Otherwise ur server skips .htaccess file.

Thank u.